# How to Force each link to open into a new IE Window via EmbeddedWB?

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, winapi

Is it possible to change all web page links to open into a new IE window instead of inside EmbeddedWB?

I would like to have a similar behaviour as when you would right click a hyper link inside EmbeddedWB and choose the context-menu option OPEN IN NEW WINDOW. The IE itself opens outside EmbeddedWb.

is it  possible to do this through OnBeforeNavigate2 without executing IE as a new process, I want to use same process.
 Reason for opening IE into same process is that that I want cookies etc to work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the cookies are shared when IE is executed like this after link click in OnBeforeNavigate2.

```
function ExecuteHtml(const URL :string): THandle;
var
  zURL, zParams, zDir: array[0..255] of Char;
  filename: string;
begin    
  Result := ShellExecute(Application.MainForm.Handle, 'open',
    pchar('Iexplore.exe'),StrPCopy(zURL, URL),
    StrPCopy(zDir, ''), SW_SHOWDEFAULT );

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to implement multi-window browsing in your application right?

In order to do this you could dynamically create a new window (a form) with TWebBrowser component on it and then navigate that TWebBrowser to specific page instead of the one that the click was made on.

Or perhaps create sort of tabbed interface where each tab would have its own instance of TWebBrowser component on it.

Or maybe you would even like to go and show that in a new instance of your own application. In such case you need to develop your application so that it can accept additional start-up parameter which will tell it to which web page should it navigate upon start.

In short each time you need to create a new instance of TWebBrowser component. And yes OnBeforeNavigate2 event is right for this as you can prevent original TWebBrowser to navigate to the page that clicked hyperlink points.

Comment: I dont want to create my own web browser, I simply want IExplorer to appear in a similar way, when you right click a link and choose OPEN IN A NEW WINDOW.

Comment: So you want to open the link in default browser instead?

Comment: I want to open link in INTERNET EXPLORER.
  Not default browser.
    Otherwise if default browser is Chrome, the cookies do not work that are stored by EmbeddedWb.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't know the correct answer. You could try opening Internet Explorer vie command-line where you specify additional parameters to control how the IE is shown or whether existing process is reused. For more information about command-line options check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks I it seems cookies are passed between new Process and Embedded, so I wrote my own code answer to this Q hope you dont mind?